# "In, into, on" The Big Problem

Tags: prepositions, difference

I have always found prepositions to be a fishy part of grammar in English.

Suppose we have a train, a bus, a car, a plane, a ship, a boat.

We can either say:

- To get in the train (bus, car, plane, ship, boat).
- To get into the train (bus, car, plane, ship, boat).
- To get on the train (bus, car, plane, ship, boat).

But what is the big difference between them.

As I feel it:

- "in" shows location and firstly means to get inside of them.
- "into" shows motion rather than the location.
- "on" means to board. But you cannot board "a car" for instance, so it doesn't always work.

Comment: @stangdon There's no **"into"**.

Comment: *Into* always means "inside".  We don't really use it with vehicles.